# Trigger selenium-java test scripts after TFS build

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, tfs, build

I have a maven project in Jenkins (which is a selenium- java project), web-Developers use TFS , I want to execute my selenium tests as soon as developers push their code change to TFS.

Comment: What's the version of your TFS server? Which build system you'd like to use? XAML or vNext?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the TFS2015 or later, to execute Java Maven Project in TFS with vNext build system, you can refer to this link for detailed steps: [Build your Java app with Maven](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/java/quick-to-azure).

If you want to build in Jenkins and just use TFS as the Version Control System, you can refer to this article to know [How to integrate Selenium C# .NET test automation codes with Jenkins](http://www.swtestacademy.com/jenkins-selenium-tfs-integration/).

Below articles also for your reference:

- [Create and run a Maven build on Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUrDCYAwIAY)
- [Getting Started with Selenium Testing in a Continuous Integration
  Pipeline with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/01/27/getting-started-with-selenium-testing-in-a-continuous-integration-pipeline-with-visual-studio/)